# Execute PHP scripts within Node.js web server

Tags: php, node.js

What steps are necessary to have a Node.js web server function like Apache executing PHP scripts? Any way to integrate PHP within Node.js?

Note: I don't want to execute PHP scripts directly within Node.js but "routed" through an Apache instance or something similar.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Node.js only supports JavaScript. Here is a tutorial on how to have PHP running with Node.js on the side.

http://blog.mixu.net/2011/01/04/nginx-php-fpm-and-node-js-install-on-centos-5-5/

Comment: I didn't even think about executing PHP scripts directly through Node.js ;) The link you posted points into the right direction though.

Answer (score 75):

I had the same question.  I tried invoking php through the shell interface, and it produced the desired result:

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec;
app.get('/', function(req, res){exec("php index.php", function (error, stdout, stderr) {res.send(stdout);});});
```

I'm sure this is not high on the recommended practices list, but it seemed to do what I wanted.  If, on the other hand, you don't want to execute PHP scripts directly from Node.js but want to relay them from another web server that does, this seems to do the trick:

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec;
app.get('/', function(req, res){exec("wget -q -O - http://localhost/", function (error, stdout, stderr) {res.send(stdout);});});
```

Comment: How to pass the parameter from Node JS to Php script?

Comment: exec("php index.php 'param1' 'param2'")

Answer (score 10):

You can run PHP as with any web-server, using the SPHP module for node.
It's compatible but not dependent on express. 
It also supports websockets requests on the HTTP port.
Its biased for speed under small load, rather then saving resources.

To install in node:

```
npm install sphp
```

in you app:

```
var express = require('express');
var sphp = require('sphp');

var app = express();
var server = app.listen(8080);

app.use(sphp.express('public/'));
app.use(express.static('public/'));
```

For more information, look at https://github.com/paragi/sphp

I'm slightly biased too because I'm the author :)

Comment: When switching pages several times (Go to PHP<=>Go to HTML) at the example: Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in node_modules\sphp\php_worker.php on line 30

Comment: Please submit bug rapports on github. I'm happy to help.

Comment: are php variables set ? such as $_SERVER and other important variables

Answer (score 7):

Take a look here: https://github.com/davidcoallier/node-php

From their read me:

> ## Inline PHP Server Running on Node.js
>
> Be worried, be very worried. The name **NodePHP** takes its name from
>   the fact that we are effectively turning a nice Node.js server into a
>   FastCGI interface that interacts with PHP-FPM.
>
> This is omega-alpha-super-beta-proof-of-concept but it already runs a
>   few simple scripts. Mostly done for my talks on **Node.js for PHP
>   Developers** this turns out to be quite an interesting project that we
>   are most likely be going to use with [Orchestra](http://orchestra.io)
>   when we decide to release our
>   **Inline PHP server** that allows people to run PHP without Apache, Nginx or any webserver.
>
> Yes this goes against all ideas and concepts of Node.js but the idea
>   is to be able to create a web-server directly from any working
>   directory to allow developers to get going even faster than it was
>   before. No need to create vhosts or server blocks ore modify your
>   /etc/hosts anymore.

Comment: The node-php on npm is a completely different project:  https://github.com/mkschreder/node-php, which works great for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to implement direct link node -> fastcgi -> php. In the previous answer, nginx serves php requests using http->fastcgi serialisation->unix socket->php and node requests as http->nginx reverse proxy->node http server.

It seems that [node-fastcgi paser](https://github.com/billywhizz/node-fastcgi-parser) is useable at the moment, but only as a node fastcgi backend. You need to adopt it to use as a fastcgi client to php fastcgi server.

Answer (score 2):

**A simple, fast approach** in my opinion would be to use [dnode-php](https://github.com/bergie/dnode-php) for that.

You can see a brief introduction [here](http://bergie.iki.fi/blog/dnode-make_php_and_node-js_talk_to_each_other/). Simple, quick and easy!

Answer (score 2):

If php is in FPM mode node-phpfpm could be an option, check the documenation https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-phpfpm

Answer (score 1):

You can use node-php to run php with node js: https://github.com/mkschreder/node-php

Answer (score 0):

You can serve PHP directly with node WAS: https://github.com/paragi/was

Comment: I no longer maintain it.

Answer (score 0):

You must check out [`node-php-fpm`](https://github.com/ivanslf/node-php-fpm).