# Can i run a php file or a html file in a node js web server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Maybe it's a stupid question but i am a newbie using node js, and I think that it can be used just with js files, I dont know, I installed node js on my windows and i started the web server but i dont know how to run the files, I have always worked with apache, I saw there is a folder called scrips in the node js installation folder

Comment: Use the Node console, in start menu write node and you will get it.

Comment: This question is already answered here..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542169/execute-php-scripts-within-node-js-web-server

Answer (score 0):

> but i dont know how to run the files, I have always worked with apache.

In NodeJS, it's either you write the web server (it's like writing Apache itself), or use a framework that does it for you (it's like adding in something like Apache). Suggesting you check out [Express](http://expressjs.com/). It's something almost close to CodeIgniter (writing points of entry).

> Can i run a php file or a html file in a node js web server?

NodeJS is for JS. Your server files are all in JS. As for HTML, checkout Express (mentioned above), or if you just want to serve plain HTML (or static files), you may want to check out [Connect Static](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static)