# How to run PHP Script in Node.js?

Tags: php, node.js

I am trying to run php code in Node.js. But while typing localhost:4000 in the browser the whole code of index.php is getting displayed in the browser.

**Node.js code**

```
var http = require('http'),
fs = require('fs'),
var app = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
fs.readFile("index.php", 'utf-8', function (error, data) {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    response.write(data);
    response.end();
}); }).listen(4000);
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php

$handle = fopen("data.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {

         echo $line;
         echo '<br>';
    }
} else {
    // error opening the file.
} 
 fclose($handle);
?>
```

So , please let me know , how can i run PHP code through node.js , suggest me some solution.

Comment: PHP needs to be interpreted, what you are doing is simply fetching the file content and displaying. I don't know why you are doing this, but this is not the way forward.

Comment: I don't think you can, you'd need php running on your server. Why would you mix Node with php. They're 2 server languages. Your Node server won't know how to interpret a php file

Comment: ok thanks , can you please suggest me , how to run PHP script through node.js

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542169/execute-php-scripts-within-node-js-web-server

Comment: You need to run PHP and pass in various environment variables… somehow. That's either a massively broad topic or a recommendation of a prewritten solution. Either way, its off-topic for SO.

Comment: If all this code is doing is reading a text file, would it not be better to convert it to Node? You can certainly run another web server in your stack to run this PHP, and you can do it on the console with a Node function to call shell commands, but there seems no need in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Node.js cannot run PHP out of the box. It is not a PHP server, and cannot parse PHP code. You might be able to use a JavaScript PHP shim, but these will likely not have reliable performance.

One such option is [php.js](http://phpjs.hertzen.com/), which is a JavaScript PHP VM, but even still, I do not recommend this.

My wholehearted recommendation is that you convert your code to Node.js if you're going to use Node.js at all. Your code is relatively trivial to convert as well. See Node.js' built in [`fs`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) API. In particular, the [`fs.readFile()`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback) function which you are already using to read the PHP file.

If you need to convert each new line into an HTML page break, that's also relatively trivial. First, you'll want to coerce the data to a string using the [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) method. You can also use Regex matching, or use `split()` and `join()` to convert newlines into `</br>`. For this example, I'll use the `split()`/`join()` method.

E.g.

```
fs.readFile('filename.txt', 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
    var str = data.toString();
    str = str.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/g).join('</br>');
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.write(str);
    res.end();
});
```