# How to Setup Dev Environment for Node.js, PHP, & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, apache, ubuntu

I am working on a web app where some of the existing code is in PHP, but much of the new development is going to be in Node.js. The backend is MySQL. In the past I've used MAMP for the LAMP stack. However what would you suggest using as a local development environment for Node.js, PHP, & MySQL?

Thank you,

Comment: Install Node Server and for mysql with node you just need to install mysql module for nodejs and for php you already have MAMP

Comment: @Haridarshan Would I run the Node.js and MAMP on different ports or the same?

Answer (score 1):

You can Node server on any port you want which is available using Node Express module

```
var app = require('express')();

var listener = app.listen(<Available_Port>, function(){
    console.log('Listening on port ' + listener.address().port); 
});
```

**MAMP apache** will run on **80** port by default, from where your php scripts will gets executed and **Mysql** on port **3306** by default

Answer (score 0):

Several packages can help you serve PHP through Node, most notably the node-php packages ([there's two](https://github.com/mkschreder/node-php) [of them](https://github.com/davidcoallier/node-php), completely unrelated to each other but generally does the same job).

Here's a sample of Node serving WordPress using [mkschreder's node-php](https://github.com/mkschreder/node-php):

```
var express = require('express');
var php = require("node-php"); 
var path = require("path"); 

var app = express();

app.use("/", php.cgi("/path/to/wordpress")); 

app.listen(9090);

console.log("Server listening!");
```

Ideally though, you should stick to either *just* Node or PHP. Node operates server-side, so does PHP. Putting PHP on a Node project makes Node redundant, and vice versa.

Further reading:

- [Execute PHP scripts within Node.js web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542169/execute-php-scripts-within-node-js-web-server)
- [How to run PHP Script in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27983067/how-to-run-php-script-in-node-js)