# process php files with node's ejs template framework

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Does node's ejs module support running php files?

I've tried running `include('header.php);`, but it just spits it out as text.

Comment: No, Node.js only supports Javascript. Related question: [Execute PHP scripts within Node.js web server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542169/execute-php-scripts-within-node-js-web-server)

Comment: Thanks. I honestly was just being a stubborn php developer, not wanting to let go of php. Going to just switch to using ejs implicitly. I'm actually going to just turn apache off and go with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else interested:

[php-node npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/php-node)

Comment: This works great, thank you. However I've decided to scrap the php side of things completely and go completely Javascript/Node. Onwards and Upwards I always say! (rarely)