# Pushing to PHP with Node.JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, node.js

We have a ROOMS database that contains different class-rooms in a School with information like real-time capacity, real-time temperature, moisture-level.... Assume that there exist Sensors to update the ROOMS database in terms of capacity, temperature, moisture...per room in real-time.

We have a PHP page (room.php) that allows a Student to See different class-rooms he is allowed in terms of capacity, temperature, moisture...

We thought of using Node.JS to push notification to clients whenever database changes.

We are currently using the following Server.js and client.html (from http://www.gianlucaguarini.com/blog/push-notification-server-streaming-on-a-mysql-database/) After installing node along with required npm libraries. The issue is that it successfully pushes data to client.html - but not to room.php. This means when we replaced client.html with room.php in the Server handler function after embedding the required client side code in room.php, we didn't get the intended results. Even we thought of using Synchronous AJAX in client.html with a url pointing to room.php - Still not working. Please tell us how to make this work.

Comment: I am also dealing with this right now. I believe from what I am reading that you need a library like express for file handling. because apache has built in file handling and evidently node.js does not. Also when I tried this making AJAX calls I ran into a whole other set of problems with same origin policy. I am literally about to start over on what I was doing and use express. I was trying to avoid using a library for learning sake but after a week of struggle I think I understand why everyone uses express...

Comment: You can't replace client.html with room.php in the server handler function because you can't serve PHP files from Nodejs. well, technically you can but their PHP code won't be "executed". I'm not sure what the PHP file contains but unless it's purely HTML it most definitely won't work. Take a look at answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542169/execute-php-scripts-within-node-js-web-server

Comment: @NichoDiaz I think you mean file *serving*, because Node actually does file handling with its native module `fs` (you have to `require` it but not install it since it's a native module). With `http` (another core module) and `fs` you technically can make a file server in node without depending on external libraries. But checkout [serve-static](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static#serve-files-with-vanilla-nodejs-http-server) which is a very small library for doing just that. (unless you also meant to serve PHP files directly via Nodejs, which you can't, check my above comment)

Comment: @laggingreflex awesome thanks man. Ya that is what I meant. Or what I was reading somewhere. And man I was thiknking he could use http or sock.io to get this done but i dindt want to say anything cause i am not educated enough yet with node. But you think that would be the way to go to handle ajax like applications? node to php and back.

Comment: I could See different mechanisms like node-php, dnode-php... to make PHP work with Node JS, I have yet to find a relevant example involving a database