# can we modify fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/index.html');?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

Can we modify `fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/game.php');` to `fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/game.php?id='+id);` ?

It gives me an error:

```
fs.js:549   return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
```

Is there any other way?

Comment: `readFileSync` is meant to read files, not execute them (which I assume is what you want).

Comment: If your meant is to execute php scripts from nodejs than [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542169/execute-php-scripts-within-node-js-web-server) you should find some help.

Comment: i dont want to execute php script.. let me tell you what i am trying to do in detail. I am a beginner in node and just started a week ago so apologies for bad code in advance. The thing is i am passing a value from my php to node in the form of localhost:8000/game.php?id=123, now here the value gets passed to node but connection doesn't gets establish since fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/game.php'); doesn't recognize the url. so is there any other way to do it? thanks for reply

Comment: What do you expect Node to do with `game.php`? It sounds like you're trying to execute PHP code from Node.

Comment: i want my node to get a value from localhost:8000/game.php?id=123 when it is called in browser by another js, which it is getting but now the io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) function is not establishing the connection since fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/game.php'); doesn't recognize the url. and if i try running  localhost:8000/game.php it establishes a connection but since there is no value passed in url, node doesn't get any value. All i want is to pass a value to my node and start a connection with my game.php

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're trying to do a `GET` call to your php service, which runs on its own (like you have a webserver which provides php pages on `localhost/game.php` or similar).

If this is the case, you need to use the [http](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) library, and I think something like this can work for you:

```
"use strict";

var http = require("http");
var id = 123;
var options = {
  host: "localhost",
  port: 80,
  path: 'game.php?id=' + id,
  method: "GET"
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log("STATUS: " + res.statusCode);
  console.log("HEADERS: " + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.on("data", function (chunk) {
    console.log("BODY: " + chunk);
  });
});

req.end();
```