# Can Run laravel 5.2 application on Node js

Tags: php, angularjs, node.js, laravel, model-view-controller

I am working on web application in which I want to use laravel 5.2 as back end development and  angular 2 in front end but I have a Question-

> Can I run Laravel 5 application on nodejs instead of Xampp? Is this possible ??

I read this, but I can't understand whether his problem is like mine or not 
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/nodejs-with-laravel

If possible, can any body give me any link to tutorial to do this thing?
Thank's

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute PHP scripts within Node.js web server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542169/execute-php-scripts-within-node-js-web-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can receive some data by node.js server and transfer it to laravel.
For example you can transfer it through Redis.
There is tutorial about it https://laracasts.com/series/real-time-laravel-with-socket-io

Comment: You can run php script from node.js by exec  package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/exec), but it's not usefull.

Comment: why is not usefull