# Sending data from server.js to a PHP file to process

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, node.js, post

When I submit a form from my client side the relevant data from the form is showing up as req.body on my server.  I want to pass that data to a PHP file to process. I don't know how to run the PHP file and pass it an argument from inside the js file.

```js
app.post('/contactengine.php' ,function ( req, res ){
  data = req.body
  //the data is showing up here correctly.
  //I would like to take data and get it processed by contactengine.php can anyone help?  I dont know how to run the PHP file and pass it an argument.
});
```

Comment: I did not quite understand. You call first `/contactengine.php` to get some data, and then you call again `/contactengine.php` attaching the date you just got before?

Comment: I have a form like this ```<form method="post" action="contactengine.php">``` and I am trying to send the data from the captured fields to a PHP file to process.  I think this would be easily normally but I'm using node and express so I'm thinking have to set up a route in my server.js file and then send req.body into the PHP file... I could be way off I'm pretty new.

Comment: Take a look at the answer @DaveCausey added on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542169/execute-php-scripts-within-node-js-web-server. He used exec within node to call the PHP executable and passed the page, you can just tack on an argument in your call... see PHP's CLI docs (http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php); check out options and usage. Alternatively, you could find a package via NPM like `exec-php` which will take care of calling the executable for you.