# How to serve php files on my express server as my home page

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, express, indexing

php is used for my home page but I know that node javascript doesn't support .php files so I wanted to know how to do it. This is my code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.php');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

And of course it's not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute PHP scripts within Node.js web server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542169/execute-php-scripts-within-node-js-web-server)

Comment: Is not express, but it might help https://github.com/jaceju/node-php-server. I'm posting as a comment because I haven't try the package

Comment: Node doesn't run php scripts. It is as simple as that. You might be able to exec the php script through the shell interface, but that would really not be recommended.

Comment: the what should i do ? i want to have socket.io in my server too

Comment: Does the server have php running on it also? If you are running Nginx or Apache you could use it to act as a proxy and pass js requests to node and php requests to php-fpm. You would have to have different routes for js vs php calls.

Comment: check ratchet.io if you need websockets, it can help you in case you only want to support websockets...

Answer (score 4):

I was looking into this with no idea. I was very confused, and then discovered this extension to node:
npm install phpcgijs --save

And voila, you can run php scripts. The documentation is at github

https://github.com/mkschreder/node-php#readme

Just discovered this and don't have much experience with it, but since it took me a lot of work to find it, I decided to share it here in case somebody is in the same boat.