# Making Azure Web App with PHP, node.js

Tags: php, node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I want to run PHP and Node.js in Azure Web app.

There are my wwwroot directory
[my wwwroot directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmtGs.png)

I only can access node.js script, how can i access php and node.js script as following URL?

I want to access : 
 `index.html` by `http://www.example.com` 
 `hello.php` by `http://www.example.com/phpscript/hello.php` 
 `chatroom.html` by `http://www.example.com/nodejsscript/chatroom.html`

And the web.config file as follow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
        </handlers>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="StaticContent">
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
                </rule>
                <rule name="app" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="iisnode.+" negate="true" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/nodejsscript/server.js" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: what's the error ?

Comment: when I access `http://www.example.com/phpscript/hello.php` , HTTP Error 500 will be show

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute PHP scripts within Node.js web server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542169/execute-php-scripts-within-node-js-web-server)

Comment: what's the contents of your hello.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you can leverage **Virtual applications and directories** to achieve your requirement.

1) Create virtual directories as below in the [Azure portal](http://portal.azure.com).

[image]

2) Move `web.config` file from `/wwwroot` folder to `/wwwroot/nodejsscript` folder, and change the following line:

```
<action type="Rewrite" url="/nodejsscript/server.js" />
```

as below:

```
<action type="Rewrite" url="server.js" />
```