# Serving moodle LMS with node.js

Tags: node.js, moodle

Is there any way to serve moodle LMS platform with node.js and mongodb; I read moodle documentation and as far as i can see it needs apache. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are certainly not limited to using Apache with Moodle, you just need a server that can run PHP scripts. In theory, it looks like Node.js can run PHP scripts ([Execute PHP scripts within Node.js web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542169/execute-php-scripts-within-node-js-web-server)) but it is probably a terrible idea ...

Apache is generally regarded as a better way to run Moodle than IIS, but NGINX should also work.

As for the database - Moodle requires a relational database that can execute SQL statements. There is built-in support for MySQL, MSSQL, PostGreSQL, Oracle, MariaDB - you could, in theory, extend this to support any other relational DB systems, but it would be a big job.

Moodle will never support non-relational databases such as MongoDB (other than as a caching solution, where it is already supported).

See https://docs.moodle.org/en/Installing_Moodle for the full list of hardware / software requirements.

Comment: thanks. My app is based on node so it would be as you say not i great idea to proceed this way. Any other idea to use LMS on node or do i have to develop my own..

Comment: You may want to consider running Moodle on a separate server and use webservices to communicate between your app and the Moodle instance. Other than that, I can't offer any advice, as I don't know of any Node.js-based LMS.