# "Cannot POST /send_form_email.php error" on contact form

Tags: php, html

I'm getting a "Cannot POST /send_form_email.php" error and have not figured out why? The files are in the same directory.  These are the only two HTML or PHP files on the site.

```
  <form id="contactform" action="send_form_email.php" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control placeholder="First Name" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">Email</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="subject">Phone</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="message">Message</label>
              <textarea id="message" rows="3" class="form-control"></textarea>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="contact-submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
        </form>
```

Here is the PHP file that it is linked to. I have double checked the file names.  and I have cleared cache to make sure the changes took.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // Sent where the email goes here
    $email_to = "jeff.a.winkler@gmail.com";
    $email_subject = "Message from Patient";
        function died($error) {
        // Error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }


    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['firstname']) ||
        !isset($_POST['lastname']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['phone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['message'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
    }



    $firstname = $_POST['firstname']; // required
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname']; // required
    $email = $_POST['email']; // required
    $phone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $message = $_POST['message']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";


    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }



    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($firstname)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($lastname)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($phone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($message)."\n";

// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php

}
```

Comment: Can you post the whole error? What webserver are you using? What throws the error?

Comment: localhost n a node server.

Comment: are you able to access the send_form_email.php directly from the browser if so is there any error ?

Comment: this is the entire error Cannot POST /send_form_email.php

Comment: The error leads me to belive there is something wrong with your server setup, and not the HTML/PHP part. What do you mean by node server? What is the webserver that runs PHP?

Comment: I am not able to directly access the file from browser

Comment: I have a npm base setup for my bootstrap sites.  and I use npm start for the server

Comment: Inorder to run a PHP code you should have  PHP setup along with apache/nginx server. nodejs uses javascript code.

Comment: You should post that part instead. And you should change the HTML/PHP code to be as minimal as possible. For example just a simple PHP files that prints the contents of `$_POST`. Either that minimal example fixes the problem, which means you have some weird PHP error, or, if the error is still there, we know it is not caused by PHP.

Comment: And as @BlackBurn027 is saying, you can not directly "run" PHP via a nodejs webserver. They are not interchangable. Please post the nodejs code

Comment: here is the github link to the site:  https://github.com/ikiru/womenswellness

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood both what nodejs is and how PHP works. For starters, you have NO nodejs server included in the GitHub code. Secondly, you can not serve PHP via a nodejs server. You can do something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542169/execute-php-scripts-within-node-js-web-server, but why would you like to do that. You should read up on PHP basics first, and look at software like Apache and Nginx. And why do you want to run this via nodejs? I don't see the point in doing that in your situation

Comment: I think I am going to have switch from the PHP to something like NPM sendmail.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code never gets executed, $_POST['email'] does not exist. In fact in your form you have absolutely no 'name=' attributes - these are essential if you want to pick up anything from the form in the $_POST array.

E.g. for an input element like e-mail, you'd specify name='email' :

```
<input type="email" name='email' class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>

$_POST['email'] will now (when submitted...) hold the e-mail address.
```

Notice the type='email' it will automatically (if browser supports the type, otherwise it reverts to text) check if e-mail address is valid 'pattern'. If you need the email address to be restricted more than just a string that looks like an email address you can use the pattern attribute - allows you to specify a regular expression the value must match for the value to be valid.

So I'd suggest you first check if the form was submitted with if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { rest of your code where you can fetch/handle values in $_POST array}

Answer (score 0):

```
 <form id="contactform" action="send_form_email.php" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
              <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control placeholder="First Name" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
              <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">Email</label>
              <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="subject">Ph`enter code here`one</label>
              <input type="text" name="telephone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="message">Message</label>
              <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="3" class="form-control"></textarea>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="contact-submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: use this one whenever we post data it recognise by name.