# What should be my Axios Post Request URL?

Tags: php, reactjs, forms, axios

I'm trying to learn to create a Form on React, and here is my code. It gives me an error *"POST http://localhost:3000/index.php 404 (Not Found)"*

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import './style.css'
import { CareerContainer, CareerWrapper, Heading, FormWrapper, Form, SubmitBtn, Input } from './elements.js'
import Navbar from '../BlackNavbar'
import axios from 'axios'
import swal from 'sweetalert';
const API_PATH = './index.php';
class App extends Component { 
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            fname: '',
            femail: '',
            fphone: '',
            mailSent: false,
            error: null
        }
    }
    handleFormSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: `${API_PATH}`,
            headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
            data: this.state
          })
        .then(result => {
            this.setState({
            mailSent: result.data.sent
            })
        })
        .catch(error => this.setState({ error: error.message }));
        swal('Your message has been succesfully been sent!');
        console.log(this.state);
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div id="careers">
                <Navbar />
                <CareerContainer>
                    <CareerWrapper>
                        <Heading>Apply now</Heading>
                        <FormWrapper>
                            <Form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                                <Input id="name" placeholder="Enter Name" type="text" name="fname" 
                                    value={this.state.fname}
                                    onChange={e => this.setState({ fname: e.target.value })}
                                />
                                <Input id="email" placeholder="Enter Email" type="email" name="femail" 
                                    value={this.state.femail}
                                    onChange={e => this.setState({ femail: e.target.value })}
                                />
                                <Input id="phone" placeholder="Enter Phone" type="text" name="fphone" 
                                    value={this.state.fphone}
                                    onChange={e => this.setState({ fphone: e.target.value })}
                                />
                                <SubmitBtn onClick={e => this.handleFormSubmit(e)}  type="submit">Submit</SubmitBtn>
                            </Form>
                        </FormWrapper>
                    </CareerWrapper>
                </CareerContainer>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

So this file's name is *'App.js'* and my *'index.php'* is inside the same folder as *'App.js'*.
It looks like

```
Forms (folder name)
|_App.js
|_index.php
|_elements.js
|_style.css
```

I'm not sure what to put the URL as to connect it to my index.php, I'm a newbie to axios and stuff. So any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute PHP scripts within Node.js web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542169/execute-php-scripts-within-node-js-web-server)

Comment: Why don't you use another server for your API ?

Answer (score 2):

`index.php` is a backend file, you should start a server like apache to run this php file!

Answer (score 0):

Now you are passing './index.php' as a URL so Axios makes a request to your react application's URL 'http://localhost:3000' + './index.php' which is not your backend's URL. So you should pass your backend's URL to Axios in order to make it work.