# Run php file in node

Tags: php, node.js, express

I have an application that I'm trying to migrate to a node server, but when it needs to query a file on my server, it always fails.

I managed to run the statics with Express, but when php makes a query it always returns an error similar to:

**Cannot POST "/path-to-file/file.php"**

The structure of the files is like this:

app

- public

  - routes

    - index.php
  - statics

    - index.html
- server.js
- package.json

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express(); 

app.listen(5000, () => console.log('Server is up and running'));

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('POST request to the homepage')
})

app.use(express.static('public'));
```

index.php :

```
<?php

 $res = '<h1>Random Title'</h1>;
 
 $echo $res;
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Socket Sender</title>

</head>
<body onload="getPage()">
<div id="table_container">
</div>
<script language=javascript>
    function getPage(){
        fetch('path/to/file', {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(body),
    })
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((data) => {
      if(data){
        console.log(data);
      }
    }
    );
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like help to know if it is possible to run these scripts in node or if I have to rewrite all of them

I'm new to node so if I said something absurd please ignore it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is a duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542169/execute-php-scripts-within-node-js-web-server